# Boost Python - Overloaded Functions with default arguments problem

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have a class that has two functions, both of which take a different set of parameters and both of which have default arguments like so:

```
void PlaySound(const std::string &soundName, int channel = 0, bool UseStoredPath = true);

void PlaySound(FMOD::Sound* sound, int channel = 0);
```

I've found how to do default argument overloads from the tutorial here

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/python/doc/v2/overloads.html

as well as how to do function overloads taking different parameter types here

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Python-def-and-member-function-overloads-td2659648.html

and I end up doing something like this...

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(PlaySoundFromFile, Engine::PlaySound, 1, 3)
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(EngineModule)
{
    class_<Engine>("Engine")
        //Sound
        .def("PlaySound", static_cast< void(Engine::*)(std::string, int, bool)>(&Engine::PlaySound));
}
```

The problem is I really have no idea how to use them together at the same time. I'd like to avoid having to change my base class function definitions.

Can someone who's done this before, or knows how to do this help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7577410/3233

Comment: There is a good guide: [Default Arguments in Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/default_arguments.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(
    PlaySoundFromFile, Engine::PlaySound, 1, 3)
BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(
    PlaySoundFromFMOD, Engine::PlaySound, 1, 2)

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(EngineModule)
{
    class_<Engine>("Engine")
        .def("PlaySound", static_cast< void(Engine::*)
            (const std::string&, int, bool)>
            (&Engine::PlaySound), PlaySoundFromFile())
        .def("PlaySound", static_cast< void(Engine::*)
            (FMOD::Sound*, int)>
            (&Engine::PlaySound), PlaySoundFromFMOD())
    ;
}
```

The trick is that you need to tell each `def()` to use one of the overload specifiers (that seemed to be the biggest missing piece from what you had).