# boost-python select between overloaded methods

Tags: c++, python, boost

Assume exist some class Foo with two overloaded methods:

```
class Foo
{
  ...
   void m1(A& a);
   void m1(B& b);
```

I need expose one of these methods over boost-python:

```
boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def("m1", &Foo::m1)
```

How should I specify that signature of `m1(A&a)` should be used over `m1(B&b)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
void (Foo::*m1)(A&) = &Foo::m1;
boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def("m1", m1)
```

Answer (score 30):

Just for completion, it is also possible to have both of them exposed at python side:

```
void (Foo::*m1_a)(A&) = &Foo::m1;
void (Foo::*m1_b)(B&) = &Foo::m1;

boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def("m1", m1_a)
    .def("m1", m1_b)
```

Answer (score 13):

While the other answers are correct there is no need to do any shenanigans with temporary variables or `static_cast`.

The `def` function prototypes look like this:

```cpp
template <class Fn>
class_& def(char const* name, Fn fn);
template <class Fn, class A1>
class_& def(char const* name, Fn fn, A1 const&);
template <class Fn, class A1, class A2>
class_& def(char const* name, Fn fn, A1 const&, A2 const&);
template <class Fn, class A1, class A2, class A3>
class_& def(char const* name, Fn fn, A1 const&, A2 const&, A3 const&);
```

As you can see the first template parameter (`Fn`) is the type of the function pointer you want to wrap. Usually, all the template parameters are deduced by the compiler for you. However, if there is an ambiguity you need to help the compiler. If the function pointer is ambiguous due to an overloaded function you have to provide the proper type explicitly. In your case:

```cpp
boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def<void (Foo::*)(A&)>("m1", &Foo::m1)
    .def<void (Foo::*)(B&)>("m1", &Foo::m1)
    ;
```

Simple, isn't it? No need to cast or capture outside. The same thing is valid for creating free standing function at the module level, i.e. using `boost::python::def`.

Comment: I don't think that your answer introduce something new in compare with @Luc Danton one. And implicit cast is still there. But anyway +1 as a correct answer/

Comment: Yep, nothing different from @luc-danton's anwer in the end. It is way cleaner and no need to type explicit `static-cast`. And I wanted to point out that one can provide types explicitly as template parameters, even partially. It is a thing people forget about.

Comment: This one works, and it is better. A forced template argument will enhanced the type restriction and correctness.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `static_cast` to specify which signature to use. With this method, you do not need to create a named function pointer while also keeping your overload resolution within the context of a single line.

```
boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def("m1", static_cast<void (Foo::*)(A&)>(&Foo::m1))
    .def("m1", static_cast<void (Foo::*)(B&)>(&Foo::m1))
```