# How to convert C++ objects to boost::python::object?

Tags: c++, boost-python

bp::extract converts bp::object to specific type.
The question is how to do vice-verse?

Let's presume I have a PointContainer and Point classes.
I need to have a function with such signature

```
bp::object get_point(const PointContainer &, const bp::object & input);
```

It should check if input argument is an integer. In that case it returns a reference to Point instance from PointContainer with corresponding index.
If it is not an integer then function checks if the input is a slice object (ex. mylist[1:10:2]). In that case it returns a copy of PointContainer.

The question is how to convert Point, PointContainer instances to bp::objects?

Some details about mentioned classes

```
class_<Point<int>>("Point")
    .def("__getitem__", get_point_item)
    .def("__setitem__", set_point_item)
    .def("__len__", get_point_size)
    .def("__str__", print_point)
    .def("__eq__", &Point<int>::operator ==)
    .def("__ne__", &Point<int>::operator !=)
    .def("set_x", &Point<int>::set_x)
    .def("get_x", &Point<int>::get_x)
    .def("set_y", &Point<int>::set_y)
    .def("get_y", &Point<int>::get_y)
;

typedef std::vector<Point<int>> PointContainer;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<PointContainer> PointContainerPtr;

class_<PointContainer, PointContainerPtr>("PointContainer")
    .def("__iter__", iterator<PointContainer>())
    .def("__getitem__", get_point)
    .def("__setitem__", set_point)
    .def("__len__", &PointContainer::size)
    .def("append", push_point)
    .def("reserve", &PointContainer::reserve)
    .def("clear", &PointContainer::clear)
;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, heretikos. Please note that tags are not supposed to be included in the title of your question. All tags can be found at the bottom of your question.

Comment: I don't know how to convert PointContainer and Point instances to bp::object.
I know how to use bp::extract to convert bp::object to specific type. But I don't know how to do vise versa.

Comment: dandan78, thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 6):

For C++ objects whose type has been exposed via `boost::python::class_`,  one can construct a Python object with an instance of a C++ object using the following [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html#object-spec-ctors):

> ```
> template <class T>
> explicit object(T const& x);
> ```
>
> **Effects**: converts `x` to python and manages a reference to it.
>
> **Throws:** `error_already_set` and sets a Python `TypeError` exception if no such conversion is possible.

---

When a type is exposed via [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html), Boost.Python will register to-python and from-python converters for the C++ type.  When the templated constructor for `object()` is used, it will check the internal registry for a to-python converter and use it if found.  The resulting Python object will have and own its own instance of the C++ object.

Here is a complete minimal example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5eddfa5a971e018) constructing `boost::python::object`s from C++ objects:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Mockup types.
class spam {};
class egg  {};

// Factory function that returns boost::python::objects.
boost::python::object make_object(std::string name)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  if (name == "spam")     return python::object(spam{});
  else if (name == "egg") return python::object(egg{});
  else return python::object();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose models.
  python::class_<spam>("Spam", python::init<>());
  python::class_<egg>("Egg", python::init<>());

  // Expose factory function.
  python::def("make_object", &make_object);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> assert(type(example.make_object("spam")) is example.Spam)
>>> assert(type(example.make_object("egg")) is example.Egg)
>>> assert(example.make_object("bogus") is None)
```

---

If different return value semantics are needed, such as the `boost::python::object` should have a reference to an existing C++ object rather than a copy, then one needs to provide [call policies](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/reference.html#models_of_call_policies) when wrapping C++ functions.

Comment: As a side note, it may be worth splitting `get_point()` into two functions with specific argument types for `slice` and `int`, then exposing each as the `__getitem__` method.  This allows Boost.Python to handle type checking and dispatching, removing the need to manually handle extraction or throwing the Python `TypeError` exception.  See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26209311/1053968) for an example.

Comment: Sure defining 2 separate functions with `slice` and `int` arguments for `__getitem__` is better solution. 
That way I should not write a code that will check for input type.
It will make much cleaner and readable code.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use *g_python_point_container_class* variable to instantiate its wrapped PointContainer class instance in order to be able to handle it with bp::object.
The mentioned global variable is initialized in the declare_pt_container() function.

P.S. having global objects is taboo in C++. I did it in this sample for simplicity.

```
    bp::object g_python_point_container_class;

    bp::object get_point(const PointContainer & points, const bp::object & input) {
        bp::extract<bp::slice> slice_extractor(input);
        if (slice_extractor.check()) {
            const bp::slice & slice = slice_extractor;
            if (slice.start().is_none() &&
                slice.stop().is_none() &&
                slice.step().is_none()) {
                // copy entire container
                bp::object obj = g_python_point_container_class(points);
                return obj;
            }
            else {
                throw ExceptionBaseError("random slicing is not implemented");
            }
        }
        bp::extract<int> int_extractor(input);
        if (int_extractor.check()) {        
            // convert Point to bp::object in the same way using
            // extracted integer as an index ....
        }
        throw ExceptionTypeError("only integer or slice object is expected");
    }

    PointContainerPtr point_container_constructor_empty() {
        return PointContainerPtr(boost::make_shared<PointContainer>());
    }

    PointContainerPtr point_container_constructor_copy(
                                        const PointContainer & pt_container) {
        return PointContainerPtr(boost::make_shared<PointContainer>(pt_container));
    }

    void declare_pt_container() {
            g_python_point_container_class =
                class_<PointContainer, PointContainerPtr>("PointContainer", no_init)
                .def("__init__", make_constructor(point_container_constructor_empty))
                .def("__init__", make_constructor(point_container_constructor_copy))
                .def("__iter__", iterator<PointContainer>())
                .def("__getitem__", get_point)
                .def("__setitem__", set_point)
                .def("__len__", &PointContainer::size)
                .def("append", push_point)
                .def("reserve", &PointContainer::reserve)
                .def("clear", &PointContainer::clear)
            ;
        }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonModuleName) {
    declare_pt_container(); 
}
```